# Confusion about extension of LLVM IR file

Tags: llvm

What is the actual extension of a LLVM IR file? Is is `.ll` or `.s`? Some sources say it is `.ll` while some points to `.s`.

Comment: I don't think that IR itself has any "standard" extension.

Comment: What is .ll extension used for?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The real answer is that it doesn't matter. The tools can accept any file you give them, they don't care about the name. The name is just a convention.

To answer more directly, the traditional extension is `.ll` (for LLVM, I presume). However, some toolchains want to treat LLVM IR the same as assembly files and hence prefer to use the `.s` extension. Myself, I prefer `.ll` because it clarifies the difference more clearly. Using LLVM tools like `llc` it's possible to transform LLVM IR to machine-specific assembly, and I like seeing the `.ll` -> `.s` transition in this case. Having LLVM IR in `.s` files would be confusing.

Comment: And when `.bc` is used?

Comment: @osgx: `.bc` is used for the binary representation of LLVM IR. Similarly to the .ll/.s duality, .bc has a duality with .o